# Loading internal JSON data to Bootgrid

Tags: jquery

I'm using Tabletop jQuery plugin to convert Google Spreadsheet data to JSON, and it outputs all the JSON data to a variable. 
Problem is, that Bootgrid accepts only urls.

In the source code it says "or use ˋfunction()ˋ", however I tried loading a function and a variable with no success.

Is it even possible to load data from a variable in this plugin?

Comment: it would be easier for us to identify your issue and try to assist you if you shared the relevant code

Comment: It's a very basic question. Basically it's ˋ$("").bootgrid({ ajax: true, url: "file.js" })ˋ and I want to load local  data simply by calling a variable.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to add additional data to a Bootgrid request:

1) Add additional data via URL

```
$("#table").bootgrid({
    /* static URL */
    url: "/static/url"
});
```

-- or

```
$("#table").bootgrid({
    /* dynamic URL */
    url: function()
    {
        return "/dynamic/url/" + id;
    }
});
```

2) Add additional data to the POST body

```
$("#table").bootgrid({
    /* static POST (be aware of the reserved properties (e.g. sort)) */
    post: {
        customId: 1
    }
});
```

-- or

```
$("#table").bootgrid({
    /* dynamic POST (be aware of the reserved properties (e.g. sort)) */
    post: function()
    {
        return {
            customId: id
        };
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. What I did in the end was presented on my other question you answered - I appeneded the JSON data using ˋ.bootgrid("append", jsondata)ˋ :)

Comment: `post` is now obsolete use `requestHandler`